# Connect to OSX via AFP over WAN with a Time Capsule on network?

Tags: network, time-capsule, afp

I have a Time Capsule set up on my LAN to handle backups between my mom's computer and my computer.

Before we had the Time Capsule, I could connect remotely to a MacBook Pro that I set up as a server through the AFP protocol easily. Instead of having to worry about using the right IP, I used `No-IP Dynamic Updater` to assign me a DNS name that I can remember.

Since the Time Capsule was installed, however, I can no longer AFP into my mac. Instead, running the following command (hostname hidden):

```
afp://****
```

Will allow me to use AFP with the Time Capsule, and allows me to log in from there and view the storage disk on the capsule.

Is there someway to connect to my mac from outside my LAN, but specify what device I want to connect to inside my LAN? Something like:

```
afp://****:10.0.1.100
```

Where `10.0.1.100` is the LAN address of my MBP server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could forward port 548 to your MBP server to get back the old behavior of allowing afp://**** to connect to your MBP server instead of your Time Capsule.  This would definitely make your Time Capsule AFP server inaccessible from the Internet and might (but I would hope not) make it inaccessible from your LAN.  Try it and see.  [Here](http://rudkerssoftwarecorner.blogspot.com/2012/04/how-to-port-forward-on-apple-router.html) is one of many web pages describing how to set up port forwarding.

You can pick any public port you want > 1024.  I'll pick 9898 for this example.  Following the instructions on the linked page, in step 4 set up port forwarding like this:

- Description: AFP access to MBP
- Public UDP Ports: 9898
- Public TCP Ports 9898
- Private IP Address: *the LAN address of your server, e.g. 10.0.1.100*
- Private UDP Ports: 548
- Private TCP Ports: 548

Then you can access your server from the internet using `afp://hostname:9898`

Comment: I know how to port forward. This isn't really a solution, however, because I do not want to get rid of the AFP to the Time Capsule...

Comment: @Charlie, if your AFP client is good you should be able to forward any port (e.g. 12345) to port 548 on your MBP and then connect from the internet at `afp://hostname:12345`

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: @Charlie, I don't know what you are asking.  You said you know how to port forward and know how to connect via AFP using a connect string and I gave you the AFP connect string to use, so I don't know what else there is to explain.

Comment: Ah sorry, I kinda know how to port forward. I usually forward the same public/private UDP/TCP ports, but I'm assuming I show,d be forwarding different ports for each one? Could you shed some light on this for me?

Answer (score 1):

Pick a random port from the outside world, forward UDP and TCP to port 548 of one device with an internal LAN IP.  Pick another port for a second device, rinse and repeat.

Forward 9898 to 548 of a Time Capsule, forward 9998 to 548 of a MacBook Pro, etc. For Charlies question, afp://my.no-ip.address:9898 will reach the TC, afp://my.no-ip.address:9998 will reach the MBP.